# How to integrate Zoom Meeting SDK in MAUI Android and Windows

Tags: xamarin.android, maui, maui-windows

I am trying to integrate Zoom SDK in MAUI for both Android and Windows

I am using Xamarin tutorials to integrate for Android as I didn't found any code reference for MAUI.

I tried but it is not working and my App is crashing after Join Metting and giving the error:
[ame.zoomsdkpro] java_vm_ext.cc:579] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallIntMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.SecurityException: getCallState: Neither user 10154 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

My Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  Relevant code should be posted and properly formatted in the body of the post, not as a link to an offsite repo.  You have also not provided any debugging details about the crash or your attempts to solve it.

Comment: @H.A.H. Why do you bother if I am asking questions, if it is irrelevant to you why are you commenting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate Zoom Meeting SDK in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75013730/how-to-integrate-zoom-meeting-sdk-in-net-maui)

Comment: Please do not post duplicates

Comment: We are in the process of upgrading our Xamarin binding library for MAUI. We have some issues. You are welcome to jump in and help sort them out! https://github.com/VisualService/dotnet-zoom-meeting-SDK/issues/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` is a dangerous permission. You need to not only declare it in the Manifest file, but also request it in the run time.

So you can use the following code to request the permission on the android:

```
# if ANDROID
   var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Phone>();
# endif
```

For more information，you can check [the official document about the permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android).